# Find an integer $x$ such that $x \equiv 3$ (mod $4$) and $x \equiv 5$ (mod $9$)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

For this question I basically used the Chinese Remainder Theorem from my book. I just want to make sure my reasoning and logic was correct:

Notice that $4$ and $9$ are relatively prime so the criterion for the CRT is met. Also note that the answer for $x$ will be unique up to modulo $4 \cdot 9 = 36$

---

Let $x_{1} = 1 - 4s = 9t$. So that,

- $x_{1} \equiv 1$ (mod $4$)
- $x_{1} \equiv 0$ (mod $9$)

Let $x_{2} = 1 - 9t = 4s$. So that,

- $x_{2} \equiv 1$ (mod $9$)
- $x_{2} \equiv 0$ (mod $4$)

We know from the CRT that:

- $x = 3 \cdot x_{1} + 5 \cdot x_{2}$

  - Now, here I tried to find values of $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ that would satisfy both congruences at once and found that $x_{1} = 9$ and $x_{2} = 28$ so that,
  - $x = 3 \cdot 9 + 5 \cdot 28 = 167$
  - Remembering that $x$ will be unique up to congruence modulo $36$ I checked to see that $167 \equiv 23$ mod($36$)
  - Thus $x = 23$

Now, I wanted to check another way and the CRT tells us that:

- $x \equiv 3$ (mod $4$) $= 3, 7, 11, 15, 19, 23, 27, 31, 34$
- $x \equiv 5$ (mod $9$) $= 5, 14, 23, ...$
- Noticed that the only number that coincides modulo $36$ is $23$ and thus $x = 23$

---

1. Is this the correct answer?
2. Are both methods equally viable in determining the correct answer?

Comment: Use `$\pmod{n}$` for $\pmod{n}$.

Comment: 5 works mod 9 but is wrong mod 4.  We may add 9 repeatedly:  5, 14, 23, where the last one is good mod 4

Comment: $-2*4+1*9=1, $ so $a=-5*2*4+3*1*9=-13$.